# duplicated result on ListView, but reference is somewhat misleading

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I do refactor ViewHolder pattern for `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter` with reference to the following link: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

My ListView items have async http-json operation which dynamically adds views into each item. But, I have a problem that several child views are attached to other items duplicated manner. maybe it is caused by reused views. but I hardly treat it.

The following source code(pasted Async loading section from above link) are hardly understand because, the line `if (mHolder.position == mPosition)` would give always `true`, wouldn't?

Does the `static class ThumbnailTask` are placed inside of the adapter class or ouside of the adapter class?
Does `static class ViewHolder` are placed inside of the adapter class also (I did. I can understand that `ViewHolder` is resigned to each visible item)?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    ...

    holder.position = position;

    new ThumbnailTask(position, holder)
        .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask {
private int mPosition;
private ViewHolder mHolder;

public ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
    mPosition = position;
    mHolder = holder;
}

@Override
protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Download bitmap here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            mHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public int position;
}
```

Comment: Is duplication count equals to list size ?

Comment: @TugrulAsik // no, it is not equal, but the position of duplication is same. maybe it is because reusing interval is same.

Comment: I think that getView called every time for creating the view. I mean that for 1st row, call one time , for the 2nd row call 2 times and etc.  (Check it in debug mode)

Comment: @TugrulAsik // thanks for your answer. let me check as your guide :)

Comment: set a debug point into getview method and run your app in debug mode ;)

Comment: @TugrulAsik // thanks for your follow-up. I found my mistakes and post answer by myself. I spend almost a week. OMG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My foolish.

I should do initialize layout of `getView()` at the `Adapter` class. For example, a child layout needs to be `GONE` or `VISIBLE`, or it has to be cleaned by `removeAllViews()` when it had attached some views of an item.

The `ViewHolder` pattern maintains each row layout status and shows it even if it is reused.